# Filter dataframe when column name-value pairs are stored in a list?

Tags: r, list, filter, tidyverse, nse

I have a dataframe like:

```
df <- tibble::rownames_to_column(USArrests, "State") %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -State)

head(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  State   name     value
  <chr>   <chr>    <dbl>
1 Alabama Murder    13.2
2 Alabama Assault  236  
3 Alabama UrbanPop  58  
4 Alabama Rape      21.2
5 Alaska  Murder    10  
6 Alaska  Assault  263
```

In a separate list object `l` I have columns and that I need to remove from the dataframe. The element names are the column names and the values correspond to rows I want to remove:

```
l <- list(State = c("Alabama", "Pennsylvania", "Texas"),
          name = c("Murder", "Assault"))
```

Hardcoded it would do this:

```
dplyr::filter(df, !State %in% c("Alabama", "Pennsylvania", "Texas"), !name %in% c("Murder", "Assault"))

   State      name     value
   <chr>      <chr>    <dbl>
 1 Alaska     UrbanPop  48  
 2 Alaska     Rape      44.5
 3 Arizona    UrbanPop  80  
 4 Arizona    Rape      31  
 5 Arkansas   UrbanPop  50  
 6 Arkansas   Rape      19.5
 7 California UrbanPop  91  
 8 California Rape      40.6
 9 Colorado   UrbanPop  78  
10 Colorado   Rape      38.7
# ... with 84 more rows
```

However, `l` changes often so I cannot/don't want to hardcode. I attempted the following, but only the last expression is being evaluated:

```
library(purrr)
filter_expr <- imap_chr(l, ~ paste0("! ", 
                     .y, 
                     " %in% c(\"", 
                     paste(.x, collapse = "\",\""), 
                     "\")")) %>% parse(text = .)

filter(df, eval(filter_expr))

   State      name     value
   <chr>      <chr>    <dbl>
 1 Alabama    UrbanPop  58  
 2 Alabama    Rape      21.2
 3 Alaska     UrbanPop  48  
 4 Alaska     Rape      44.5
 5 Arizona    UrbanPop  80  
 6 Arizona    Rape      31  
 7 Arkansas   UrbanPop  50  
 8 Arkansas   Rape      19.5
 9 California UrbanPop  91  
10 California Rape      40.6
# ... with 90 more rows
```

Is there a way to filter `df` when the filter criteria are stored in a structure like `l` that is more idiomatic to the tidyverse?

I considered this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46155223/6382434), however, the expressions are not dynamic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could use `across` in `filter` looping over the `names` of 'l', created the logical expression by subsetting the 'l' using the key from column name (`cur_column()`) and negate (`!`).  Note that `cur_column()` works currently only with `across` and not `if_all/if_any` (`dplyr` -`1.0.6` on `R 4.1.0`)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   filter(across(all_of(names(l)), ~ !. %in% l[[cur_column()]]))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 94 x 3
#   State      name     value
#   <chr>      <chr>    <dbl>
# 1 Alaska     UrbanPop  48  
# 2 Alaska     Rape      44.5
# 3 Arizona    UrbanPop  80  
# 4 Arizona    Rape      31  
# 5 Arkansas   UrbanPop  50  
# 6 Arkansas   Rape      19.5
# 7 California UrbanPop  91  
# 8 California Rape      40.6
# 9 Colorado   UrbanPop  78  
#10 Colorado   Rape      38.7
# … with 84 more rows
```

---

We could make use of `if_all` if we can set an attribute

```
library(magrittr)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(all_of(names(l)), ~ set_attr(., 'cn', cur_column()))) %>% 
  filter(if_all(all_of(names(l)), ~ ! . %in% l[[attr(., 'cn')]]))
```

---

Or with `imap/reduce`

```
library(purrr)
df %>%
    filter(imap(l, ~ !cur_data()[[.y]] %in% .x) %>%
                 reduce(`&`))
```

---

Or another option is `anti_join`

```
for(nm in names(l)) df <- anti_join(df, tibble(!! nm := l[[nm]]))
```

Comment: +1, What does `cur_data` do here since the data aren't grouped? I assume it just returns the entire data frame?

Answer (score 2):

Another potential option here is to use `purrr` to create a logical vector that allows for `&` versus `|` conditions and can access the current column name (`.y`) without `cur_column`, which can only be used inside of `across`:

```
df %>% 
  filter(imap(l, ~ !df[[.y]] %in% .x) %>% reduce(`&`)) # can use magrittr::and
```

**Output**

```
   State      name     value
   <chr>      <chr>    <dbl>
 1 Alaska     UrbanPop  48  
 2 Alaska     Rape      44.5
 3 Arizona    UrbanPop  80  
 4 Arizona    Rape      31  
 5 Arkansas   UrbanPop  50  
 6 Arkansas   Rape      19.5
 7 California UrbanPop  91  
 8 California Rape      40.6
 9 Colorado   UrbanPop  78  
10 Colorado   Rape      38.7
# ... with 84 more rows
```

---

With the **or** variant being:

```
df %>% 
  filter(imap(l, ~ !df[[.y]] %in% .x) %>% reduce(`|`)) # can use magrittr::or
```